# Statsd dies after few hours

Tags: graphite, statsd

I have a running instance of statsd with graphite that I built like 1.5 years ago and it works seamlessly so far. Because of decommissioning that machine, I need to build a new one on the same OS;ubuntu 14.04
What I see is that though all that config files are identical, statsd dies within less than 2 hours. While statsd does not work, graphite takes data thru 2003 port just fine.I checked the mem,cpu, disk, all looks just ok...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not the answer your are looking for, but have you looked http://prometheus.io ? It's way simpler to setup up (just an yaml) with some other goodies, and you can forward the metrics from statsd with the [exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter)

Comment: The issue is with statsd not graphite. I will check prometheus but at this point, I need to get the statsd working as expected

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Statsd not happy with latency. Same configuration,OS, hardware works just fine when it is in same datacenters with the producers.